# Beta function with different integral limits

Tags: integration, beta-function

The beta function is

$$B(x,y) = 2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^{2x-1}\theta \sin^{2y-1}\theta d\theta$$

for positive values of $x$ and $y$.

How can this integral be used to evaluate other limits of integration?

For example,

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi} \sqrt{\sin\theta} \, d\theta$$

Comment: In this case, $\sin (\pi - \theta) = \sin \theta$ helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi} \sqrt{\sin\theta} \, d\theta &= \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{\sin\theta} \, d\theta + \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \sqrt{\sin\theta} \, d\theta \\
&= \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{\sin\theta} \, d\theta + \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{\sin(\theta + \pi/2)} \, d\theta \\
&= \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{\sin\theta} \, d\theta + \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{\cos\theta} \, d\theta \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \, \left( B\left(\frac{3}{4}, \frac{1}{2} \right) + B\left( \frac{1}{2} , \frac{3}{4}\right) \right) \\
&= B\left(\frac{3}{4}, \frac{1}{2} \right) = \frac{4\pi}{s},
\end{align}
where $s$ is the [lemniscate constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LemniscateConstant.html).

Answer (score 2):

$B(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4})=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{\sin(\theta)} d\theta=\int_0^{\pi} \sqrt{\sin(\theta)}d\theta$
(see Daniel comment for the last step)
More generally, special values for x an y yield specific powers of the trigonometric functions